# Angular 4 Can't bind to 'NgModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, input, bind

I'm trying to use NgModel inside a

```
<input [(NgModel)]="studiedSubject.value">
```

And I get : 
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'NgModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

I saw there is a lot of answers on this and I tried them all

in app.module.ts

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
FormsModule],

declarations: [
AppComponent,
MainComponent,
SearchComponent,
MyStudentComponent     
],

providers: [PlayerService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

in my-student.component.ts

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

I tried to delete node_modules directory and re install its content with npm install, I tried the same thing  after getting last angular cli etc..

Thanks for not tagging this question as duplicate as I wrote that I saw there is already lots of answers on this and I tried them all, also you marked it as duplicate of an answer saying to import formsModule, it's clear that I imported it..

Comment: Check this https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-does-cant-bind-to-x-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-y-mean

Comment: spelling wrong, `ngModel`

Comment: it is ngModel not <input [(NgModel)]="studiedSubject.value">